# Can I serialize a List<string> with tomba Netserializer

Tags: c#

I am using tomba [netserializer](https://github.com/tomba/netserializer) and it's very good so far, but is there is any way to serialize a list of strings? For example I have this packet

```
[Serializable]
 public class getUsernames: IPacket {
  public List < string > users {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public void Send(Connection c) {
    c.Send(this);
  }
}
```

and in the serialize types list I added

```
typeof(getUsernames)
```

but when I send the packet I don't get any response from any packet but if I remove it everything works fine

So how can I serialize a list ?

Comment: Use `string[]` instead of `List<string>`

Answer (score 1):

Before expecting a library to do magic maybe it is a good idea to look at the documentation to see what behaviour is offered?

The docs have quite a good list of what it can serialise, and lists are not on it.

What are is arrays so you could call .ToArray() on your list?

Comment: if you take a look on the "Supported Types" you will see "Dictionary" so can i serialize a Dictionary ? because i have already tried